# MS Access Split Database - Run time error with backend in new drive location?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access split database and I'm trying to get it to work with the backend on a new, more secure drive on our network. I've used a UNC path for the backend location.

This database has been running without problem on another drive which is totally public to everyone in the company (~4k people, not secure) for about a year. We have a generic account for users to access the database throughout our factory and haven't encountered this problem before I tried to switch it to the new drive. I've contacted our IT department and they've given myself and all my user's accounts read/write access to the drive, but only I can run it.

Other user accounts get these problems...

- All of my forms with objects bound to a table immediately throw a runtime error before even getting to Form_Load.
- My userforms will run DLookup functions and execute message boxes but throw a runtime error when they go to execute a query.
- I've tried using an 'On Error goto' to try and actually find the problem but it throws a runtime error before that.

I can't think at all what the problem might be. IT have told me I have the same permissions as the other users. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: can the other users open the linked tables ?

Comment: No, they can only open the database in a sort of 'display mode'. I've tried doing it before on a user account with the navigation panel enabled and everything and it just doesn't load any forms.

Comment: I rephrase my question: do the tables properly open from the other users machines ? (if the tables don't open, don't lose time to examine the forms!)

Comment: The users only see the tables through subforms. Forms with bound controls just cause an error when I try to open them, and one form without bound controls opens up but doesn't display the content, just the form header. Its like any interaction with the backend tables at all causes an error.

Comment: that's hopeless ! (your reply)

Answer (score 0):

In the front end of your DB you may have to change the path which links to the tables. The tables are in the back end of the database, which you have now moved and therefore changed the filepath. the frontend wont find them. You can delete the table links in the front end then use *External data > import and Link > Access.* In order to re-link the tables using their new filepath. You would then need to redistribute your frontend to the users.

I'm not sure if you have already done this, however, you haven't suggested so in your question. hope this helps, apologies if it was helpless.

Comment: All my tables are pointing to the right place yeah, I used a UNC path to for them too as I did with the previous drive without any issues.

Comment: ah ok. It seems obscure but I'll keep thinking. Unfortunately, I Couldn't add a comment before as I don't have enough reputation. What are the run-time error numbers that users are getting?

Comment: It won't even show the error numbers, even if I use 'On Error goto x' with 'MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description'. It just gives the standard 'Execution of this application has stopped...' message and closes down.

Comment: well I am stumped on this. I recently had an issue where I installed access runtime on a PC and any interaction with the backend threw back errors. It was due to the new PC not having a registry key stating that the trusted filepath/location. Don't think it is likely but worth checking your regedit to see if the new backend location is trusted?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have found an answer to this. I wanted to answer as well, because I had the exact same problem yesterday. It turned out that the location was referring other users back to the folder's shortcut name versus it's full length name (it is called the W drive on my computer and the K drive on theirs). I solved the issue by spelling out the name in full.